# Problem install Grover on Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, grover-gem

I am trying to integrate Grover into my project on Google App Engine (GAE) Standard, `ruby30` environment.
When I try to print a pdf I get the following message:

```
Grover::DependencyError (Cannot find module 'puppeteer'. The module was found in '/workspace/package.json' however, please run 'npm install' from '/workspace')
```

Everything works correctly in the development environment
This the line added to my `package.json` under `dependencies`

```
"puppeteer": "^21.7.0",
```

I tried to add also:

```
"scripts": {
  "gcp-build": "npm run build && npx @puppeteer/browsers install chromium --path /workspace/puppeteer"
},
"puppeteer": {
  "cacheDirectory": "/workspace/puppeteer"
},
```

Thanks for any tips

**Edit:**
I solved my problem by moving puppeteer to a Cloud function that I call from the project in GAE.

Comment: Kindly post your solution as an answer so that it would be helpful to other community members.

Comment: Sure even if it avoids the context of the question. It is no longer like installing Grover on GAE but becomes like installing Puppeter and using it in a Google Cloud functions that can then be called from any application with a POST

Answer (score 2):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

As mentioned by @Mauro

> It is no longer like installing Grover on GAE but becomes like installing Puppeter and using it in a Google Cloud functions that can then be called from any application with a POST